# Tools for testing web services

Tags: .net, web-services, testing, asmx

I want to perform integration testing of my webservices before shipping them out and am wondering if anyone can point out some tools for performing these tests automatically?

I have both ASMX webservices as well as a few WCF ones.

I want to be able to add this as a task to my build scripts and execute automatically if possible.

What are the pitfalls if any when it comes to integration testing webservices?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org).

Comment: Can you run soap ui from console as I want to add this as a task to my build scripts similar to nunit?

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is a java application, but of course it can also be used for .NET web services. You can create scripts (sending SOAP requests) and monitor the results both in text and graphically. It can emulate high - traffic conditions and in general is very configurable.

I don't have any tips specific for testing web services, other than you definitely need to stress test under heavy load conditions.

Regarding running the tests in a script, there is an [ant task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php) for running JMeter. Since you are building .NET services, I understand that this may mean too much work for setting up  the testing environment. There is of course Nant, but I don't know if it is compatible with the specific task.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) - Web Application Testing In *.Net* .
Maybe it can help with Web Services.